# A set is null set

Tags: measure-theory

This is the problem I found. If $f∈L^+$ and $∫f<∞$, then show that $\{x:f(x)=∞\}$ is a null set and $\{x:f(x)>0\}$ is σ− finite.

I tried using MCT but I couldn't proceed. 
what should I do to proceed further ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hints: For the first part, let $E=\{x:f(x)=\infty\}$. Then $\int f\ge \int_E f=?$.

For the second, can you see why each set $\{x:f(x)>a\}$ must be finite, for $a>0$? What would happen if they were infinite (use a similar trick to first part)? You can then write $\{x:f(x)>0\}$ as a countable union of such sets.

Comment: I am still not getting :(
Could you please elaborate ? Thanks